# minimize some windows, but not all, via keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors

My office is open to a room in my house that has a lot of traffic through it, and in a lot of cases, passerbys will try to look into my office and at what I am working on. Sometimes I will be working on something that I will not want these passerbys to see, and most of these times I cannot minimize these windows fast enough to prevent the text on them from being read. If I use the "Show Desktop" button at the right end of my startbar, then it minimizes all of my windows, which, from my experience, raises suspicssion in said passerbys, provoking them to ask me what I am hiding on my computer. Once again, I cannot close all of the windows I do not visible fast enough by manully dragging my cursor over to each window and pressing minimize- I have 3 very large monitors, one of which operates at 4K resolution, so If my cursor is on the furthest left monitor and I have to go to the furthest right monitor It can be hard.

Essentially what I need is somthing that will enable me to press a couple of keys on my keyboard, and if a select list of applications are open or not minimized, then they will be minimized. Say I have a game and a browser on one of my monitors, VLC on one of the other ones, and a chat window on the last monitor; What I need is a shortcut that will let me minimize the chat window and the VLC window, but not the game or the browser- Regardless of what window is selected. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry- sarcasm is my first language; English my second. But yours is a good question, so an upvote from me it gets.

Comment: HAH, Thanks for the response, Gave me a good laugh!

Comment: Have you thought about using Virtual Monitors like Dexpot. Because in windows, afasik you can only minimise one window at a time using Alt + Space + N. (You can probably use AutoHotKey to write a custom shortcut though)

Comment: I have thought about it, though in honesty, I find that such software would defeat the purpose of having 3 monitors. Besides, From my experience these softwares can me somewhat taxing on my computer's resources.

Comment: Take screenshots of some harmless documents and then set Windows to cycle through them as your desktop background.

Comment: @Ben See [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/program-to-minimize-certain-programs-only)

Comment: Thanks @ṧнʊß but I would have appreciated you linking me to that stackexchange site to ask the question myself instead of asking it for me and taking all of the credit for it.

Comment: @BenFranchuk It was not about 'credit' - I upvoted this question because I was interested. I was interested in this question - I generally use Win+D to minimize everything, so I asked this question. If you want 'credit' I can edit that question now, but SE sites are never about 'credit'

Comment: @ṧнʊß By credit I am refering to the reputation that you earned for that question. I don't really care to be honest, Im just mentioning it.

Comment: @BenFranchuk OH, reputation. I earned only 15 rep. You've earned 5 rep for this question. If you really care about 'reputation', add an answer here, and I'll +1 it. 10 more rep. Happy?